# How Spring ApplicationContext creates POJO and then do beans from them with constructor dependencies?

Tags: spring, dependency-injection, applicationcontext

I've learned that ApplicationContext firstly create JOPOs. And only then BeanPostProcessor "do spring magic".
So my question is - why there is no Exception when JOPO with constructor arguments will be created? On this phase there is no beans, no Objects that could be passed to constructor.